# Too much butter in pie crust

Tags: baking, science

My pie crust does not look right . I put in one and one half cups of butter instead of one and one half sticks.  I’ve already added the liquid. Can it be saved?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice!  Some questions to help you with your question:  (1) what size is a "stick" of butter in your part of the world?  Is this a US "stick"?  (2) if you added it by the cup, does that mean you melted it first? (3) how much pie crust are you making?

Comment: The traditional stick of butter is eight ounces. I put in  six 4 ounce sticks  (half sticks ) which is a relatively new product which confused me.

Comment: Robyn: just so you know, a "stick" or "block" of butter can be different sizes in different parts of the world.  Just in case you use a foreign cookbook.

Answer (score 3):

Six eight ounce sticks is enough butter for four regular crusts.
I'd add 3X all the other ingredients, mix, press into shape, divide into 4 pieces, freeze 3 of them, and make a pie with the remaining crust. After sitting at least a day, and perhaps freeze/thawing, you probably won't get the *best* crusts, but they should be usable.

Comment: er, in the comments the OP mentioned it was six 4-ounce sticks added - so enough for two crusts would make sense.

Comment: @Megha You're right. I've never seen 4oz. sticks.

Comment: They aren't too exotic, just regular sticks, cut in half lengthwise, and separately wrapped.  I guess it's more convenient for some, to have it neatly pre-portioned, though I don't know why they bother - I certainly don't care enough to pick one over the other

Comment: The one pound blocks, which i *have seen*, are hard to work with in family scale cooking.

Comment: Yeah, I can guess - I've used the two pound rolls for some specific cooking, it's rather difficult to portion... if I wasn't prone to hand-waving amounts (assorted half-of-that and quarter-of-remainder) it would have driven me nuts, and that at least was for a specific occasion, not regular cooking