# Too much butter in my dough

Tags: dough

I added a cube of butter, meant for the filling, to the dough for pecan tassies. Now I have too much butter in my dough. Can this be fixed?

Comment: Welcome to the Cooking Stack. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site. We see a lot of "I added too much "XYZ", help" on this site so I'll vote to close as there are lots of answers which tell you what to do already. Don't worry, this is a perfectly normal function on Stacks, where we aim to have one question for each topic. See link in next comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Too much butter in pie crust](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/94193/too-much-butter-in-pie-crust)